# When using the AVG() SQL function, is NULL part of the average or is it ignored?

Tags: sql

I'm trying to get the average price of all products, several of which are `NULL`. I want to know if when I use the following query:

```
SELECT AVG(Price) AS PriceAverage FROM Products;
```

if it is including the products that have `NULL` as a price or is it skipping them?

Comment: [Returns the average of the values in a group. Null values are ignored.](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177677.aspx)

Comment: Do you *want* it to include `NULL`s? If so, how should they be included? Treated the same as `0` values or something else?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The only aggregate function that doesn't ignore NULL values is COUNT(*). Even COUNT() ignores NULL values, if a column name is given.

Read more about it here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html

Answer (score 5):

`Null` values are ignored. If you want to include `Null` values in your average:

```
SUM(Price) / Count(*)
```

Answer (score 3):

`Null` values are ignored by the `AVG` function.